# How we can search any word is searchable on sunspot solr on rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, ruby-on-rails-3.2, sunspot-solr

How can i search full text with sentence and search any word matched.

ex:-

"may i find" is searching in model ttle

it have to display result which matched the either words of "may", "i", "find"

```
test = Model.search do 
  fulltext key do
    fields(:title)
    query_phrase_slop 1
  end
  without(:field_disabled, true)
  facet(:obj_type)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got output just search key is also accepts array of words, so simply we can get this by below code

```
def custom_search
test = Model.search do 
 fulltext key do
  fields(:title)
  query_phrase_slop 1
 end
 without(:field_disabled, true)
 facet(:obj_type)
end
if test.hits.size==0 #check the condition for no result matched for full text and passing every word
test = Model.search do 
 fulltext key.split(' ') do # key.split(' ') code make total sentence into array of words
  fields(:title)
  query_phrase_slop 1
 end
 without(:field_disabled, true)
 facet(:obj_type)
end
end
return test
end
```

Comment: @Subbarao [can you solve this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18820145/rails-sunspot-solr-search-by-keywords) I am working for two days but i could not find solution for it

Comment: Yes, I done with splitting the sentence into multiple word by .split(' ')