# rails sunspot solr search by keywords

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I am working around search for 2 days to query keyword search using `sunspot solr`. I am unable to understand

My expected output is

if i search for `laptops in US` it should search for laptop and us

But the below code search only laptops and not the other words. How can i achieve it.

My fulltext is working good

I have edited `schema.xml`

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15"/>
      </analyzer>

      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

MY model contains

```
searchable do
        text :title,:description,stored: true
        time :updated_at
        text :product do
            product.name if product
        end
        text :product_model do
            product_model.name if product_model
        end
    end
```

My controller is

```
@search = Post.search do
      fulltext params[:search] do
        query_phrase_slop 1
      end
    end
```

**Edit 1**

I have two row with `pizza` in one column and `post` in other column. If i search for `pizza` it returns 5 result if i search for `post` it returns 1 result. And finally if i search for `pizza post` it results none. But expected output is to get 6 result.

I changed `fulltext params[:search] do` to `keywords params[:search] do`

**Edit 2**

```
def index
    @search = Post.search do
      fulltext params[:search].split(' ') do
        phrase_slop 1
      end
    end
    @posts = @search.results
end
```

Comment: 'us' is probbly on stopwords list, looks like it gets excluded despite of not including explicitly `StopFilterFactory`, maybe try adding `KeepWordFilterFactory` with `us` in it? Also, you may try changing `NGramFilter` to `ShingleFilter`, it might give better results, here`re  the docs for reference: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters

Comment: search is not limited to `us` alone `computer with rate of $2500` this statement should search both computer and $2500

Comment: @zrl3dx can you please check my `edit 1`

Comment: Ok, i've tested it locally, can you test following setup: `fulltext params[:search].split(' ')` ?

Comment: @zrl3dx See my `edit 2` changed as you mentioned but same problem occurs

Comment: Ok, remove also `stored: true` from your model's `text` field and reindex.

Comment: @zrl3dx Tried removing `stored` not working same status

Comment: OMG, I've missed the obvious option which was added in my config - I think I've too tired ;) I promise, that's last change, if that still won't help, I surrender. You can leave all options like you had them but add `minimum_match 1` next to `query_phrase_slop`. It's logical, even in source it is clearly written that if no value provided, all terms must match, duh.

Comment: @zrl3dx your great after many days i find a solution for it with your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, we've found what's wrong (comments), but I'll put this as an answer so question may be closed as answered.

You should add `minimum_match` to your `search` block, i.e.:

```
@search = Post.search do
      fulltext params[:search] do
        query_phrase_slop 1
        minimum_match 1
      end
    end
```

If that option is not provided, it defaults to 'all terms match' ([source](http://sunspot.github.io/docs/Sunspot/DSL/Fulltext.html#minimum_match-instance_method)).

Comment: Can't believe that I lost 4 hours looking for this... This should be on the documentation (regarding query_phrase_slop, as warning)!